# Why can't I access the default http://localhost:80 IIS server website outside my virtual box VM on windows server 2008r2?

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtual-machines, virtualbox

I have successfully downloaded an installed [Windows Server 2008 R2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11093) evaluation into my [virtual box](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) virtual machine.

Once I booted into this evaluation copy of windows, I installed IIS7 and successfully accessed the default IIS7 website (the one that says "welcome" in a bunch of different languages).  I used internet explorer 8 to connect to localhost:80 and it worked perfectly.

The problem I'm having is accessing this default website from outside my VM from the host machine (my mac pro running Yosemite). When I load up Safari 8 and try to access localhost I get an error message indicating it couldn't find the page.

My Windows Server 2008 virtual machine network settings are set to NAT. I tried to switch them to "bridged", but still no success.  So now I am thinking there must be some security settings turned on (perhaps, firewall, or something) that is preventing me from accessing IIS7 inside the VM.

I would appreciate it if the windows server community could offer some advice.

Answer (score 1):

Localhost means "this machine" which would be looking for a web server running on your mac pro instead of the VM. From your mac pro, you should try to connect to the VM's name instead of localhost.

If that doesn't work, then make sure the firewall has port 80 open on the VM. (If you need to remove this from the equation, you could temporarily turn the firewall off completely)